# Dynamic Filtering of Array with Multiple Confitions

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, dynamic-arrays

I have an array which is constructed using user input values and can have any length:

```
var products = [
 {key1: string1,
  key2: 1,
  key3: 30,
  key4: 1},

 {key1: string2,
  key2: 2,
  key3: 35,
  key4: 2}
]
```

And I have some filters

```
var filters = {
  key2: 1,
  key3: {min: 20, max: 40},
  key4: 1,
}
```

I'm currently using the below function to filter products using my filters

```
        function multiFilter(array, filters) {
            const filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);
            return array.filter((item) => {
                // flipped around, and item[key] forced to a string
                return filterKeys.every(key => !!~String(item[key]).indexOf(filters[key]));
            });
        }

        var filtered = multiFilter(products, filters);
        console.log(filtered);
```

Everything works as expected when key3 in filters has an exact number, but I'm running into issues when trying to incorporate a range. How would I amend the function to allow for a range in key3 (filters)?

Comment: FYI [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) is much nicer than `indexOf` for detection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this approach would be useful

```js
const products = [
 {key1: 'string0',key2: 0,key3: 10,key4: 1},
 {key1: 'string1',key2: 1,key3: 15,key4: 1},
 {key1: 'string2',key2: 2,key3: 20,key4: 1},
 {key1: 'string3',key2: 3,key3: 25,key4: 2},
 {key1: 'string4',key2: 4,key3: 30,key4: 2},
 {key1: 'string5',key2: 5,key3: 35,key4: 2},
 {key1: 'string6',key2: 6,key3: 40,key4: 4},
 {key1: 'string7',key2: 7,key3: 45,key4: 4},
 {key1: 'string8',key2: 8,key3: 50,key4: 4},
 {key1: 'string9',key2: 9,key3: 55,key4: 4}];
 
const filters = {
  key2: {max: 7},
  key3: {min: 20, max: 60},
  key4: 4,
};

const filterProdacts = (products, filters) => {
// First, we create an object where the property values (min, max, eq) 
// are predicate functions.
  const fns = {
    eq: (key, value) => (obj) => obj[key] === value,
    min: (key, value) => (obj) => obj[key] >= value,
    max: (key, value) => (obj) => obj[key] <= value,
  };

// Generates a predicate based on the conditions
  makePredicat = (filterKey, filterValue) => {

// For consistency мake the numeric values as an object like { eq: 5 }
    const filterObj = (typeof filterValue === 'object') 
      ? filterValue
      : { eq: filterValue };
      
// Pick a function from fns and initialize it with the condition parameters
    return Object.entries(filterObj)
      .map(([condKey, condValue]) => fns[condKey](filterKey, condValue));
  };
  
// Fill in the array with predicate functions for each condition. 
// In this example there will be 4 functions, one for each condition 
// key2 - max: 7; key3 - min: 20; key3 - max: 60; key4 - eq: 4;
const predicats = Object.entries(filters).flatMap(([key, value]) => makePredicat(key, value));

// Initializing reduce by source array 
// then filtering it with all predicate functions
return predicats.reduce((acc, fn) => acc.filter(fn), products);
};

console.log(filterProdacts(products, filters));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Comment: upvoted this, But I think it would be nice if you add some comments on the code so other users would understand what each functions does as this type of coding is not really for beginners.

Comment: @IamL Thanks for the advice. Added comments to the code, hope they are helpful